# aws - add lastModified on every api call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am using aws lambda, api gateway and dynamodb for serverless backend.

I've created over 30 lambda functions.

Clients request for adding lastModifiedTime on every api call.
For example, every time I send api request on endPoint /user, I need to record that timestamp.

I am thinking of creating a new table in dynamodb storing the lastModifiedTime and path, but I do so, I need to add some code of All of my tables.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add that to each object? Like for a user just add a lastModifiedTime to the user record and update it whenever the user is changed?

Comment: @Jason Wadsworth do you mean I should add a new field `lastModifiedTime ` on every table? If yes, I need to update every function to achieve it

Comment: @CCCC DynamoDB is a NoSQL database? You are not really updating any tables. Only the hash and sort keys have to be defined. Everything else is up to you and does not follow any schema? Every record in your table could have hundreds of attributes that no other record in your table has. If your code breaks if you add a new attribute then I would strongly recommend checking your code. That should not happen. Writing the timestamp is a different matter. You have two options here: either update the Lambdas to write the value or use DynamoDB streams to update the records.

Comment: Be careful with the stream option. It would be easy to find yourself in a constant update loop. You'd need to be sure that there was a change outside of just the update date.